# How to build multiple bundles using Vite similar to Multi Compiler mode(multi config) in Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, vite, webpack-4, webpack-5

I have an app which has a main index.html with main.js . But there are also external scripts(libraries) that are injected into index.html programatically from inside main.js . All those scripts(libraries) are built differently because they need different aliases ,plugins ,loaders and folder structure .

In webpack we have [Multi-compiler-mode](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations) where we can export multiple webpack configs in an array and webpack will build all those different entry points accordingly as specified in respective configs  .
Is there a way to do this in Vite? (Library mode doesnt seem to be a solution in this case as i need more than just different module types)

Comment: There's also option to parameterize 1 vite config file like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76517896/14098260

Answer (score 2):

My guess you can make any number of build configs you like and then just run them in parallel with gnu parallel/xargs/gulp:

```
-c, --config <file> Use specified config file (string)
```

https://vitejs.dev/guide/cli.html

The command line could look like that:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name vite*.config.*js | xargs -P0 -n1 npx vite build -c
```

In this case you can have several configs like:

```
vite.config.mjs
vite.lib.config.js
vite.vendor.config.js
```

There's also option to parameterize 1 vite config file like described here: [How do I completely disable chunking in Vite and Rollup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76517758/how-do-i-completely-disable-chunking-in-vite-and-rollup/76517896#76517896)