# Bundling service worker with modules using Vite and Rollup

Tags: vue.js, service-worker, vite, rollupjs

I need some help with bundling a service worker that uses modules in a Vue3 project with Vite. Modules inside service worker are not supported in firefox, so I need a bundler to help me with that. I'm using vite and my rollupOptions currently look like this ([taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71355290/prevent-service-worker-js-from-being-bundled-with-vite-rollup)):

```
rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        app: './index.html',
        serviceWorker: './serviceWorker.js'
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: assetInfo => {
          return assetInfo.name === 'serviceWorker'
             ? '[name].js'                  // put service worker in root
             : 'assets/js/[name]-[hash].js' // others in `assets/js/`
        }
      },
    }
```

It outputs the service worker in root of dist directory and bundles all other files inside assets. Service worker is not going to be able to register in Firefox due to the usage of modules.

I've tried changing the format to 'iife', but Rollup is going to complain that it doesn't support code splitting.

How can I configure rollup to bundle the service worker in a way that is going to make it possible to work in browsers that don't support modules in workers? Thanks for help

## Solution:

I went with one config file with separate modes. First the app mode gets executed with emptyOutDir set to true and then the worker mode. Here's the config in case it's ever helpful to anyone:

```
    const baseConfig = {
  plugins: [vue(), mkcert()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  }
}

export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
  if (mode === 'app') {
    return {...baseConfig,
      build: {
        emptyOutDir: true,
        rollupOptions: {
          input: {
            app: './index.html'
          },
          output: {
            entryFileNames: () => 'assets/js/[name]-[hash].js',
            inlineDynamicImports: false,
          },
        }
      },
      
    }
  }

  if (mode === 'worker') {
    return  {
      ...baseConfig,
      build: {
        emptyOutDir: false,
        rollupOptions: {
          input: {
            serviceWorker: './serviceWorker.js'
          },
          output: {
            entryFileNames: () => '[name].js',
            inlineDynamicImports: true,
          },
        }
      },
    }
  }
  return baseConfig;
})
```

Commands:

```
    "build-app": "vite build --mode app"
    "build-worker": "vite build --mode worker"
    "build": "run-s type-check build-app build-worker"
```

Comment: I answered this already : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76517758/how-do-i-completely-disable-chunking-in-vite-and-rollup/76517896#76517896. Also read the comments, the OP went of making 2 Vite config files. You can build several Vite configs at once: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76272727/how-to-build-multiple-bundles-using-vite-similar-to-multi-compiler-modemulti-co/76272803#76272803. If you like my answers, don't forget to upvote them (the arrow up), that way i'll be motivated to help you in the future, thanks

Comment: You could find my other Vite related answers useful : https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A14098260+vite

Comment: Yes, thank you. When I set emptyOutDir to false and build it twice it works. I'll probably end up with two configs too. Seems like I don't have enough rep points to vote for your answer, but thanks for help